# How to add an "All" category to the tag cloud?

Tags: categories, widgets, tags

I'm using the tag cloud widget in my sidebar that displays my categories and would like to include an "All" link at the top. Any ideas how to accomplish this? Note, I would like to keep using the tag cloud widget but *could* modify the php in my sidebar doc to have more control if that's the only way.

Comment: What does your "all" link do? navigate to an archive of all posts that have *any* tag? to *all posts*? hide/show all tags in the widget? navigate to a list of all tags?

Comment: Filters posts to show posts containing all categories.

Comment: "Filters posts to show posts containing all categories" - Isn't that... all posts!?